# Does npm or yarn clone from VCS and run build script when install a package?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I am studying about npm and I have some questions.

1. Where the npm get the package from? i.e. when run `npm install <package-name>` or `yarn add <package-name>`.
2. When get the package, do npm get the package as raw or get then build it(like run the build script written in `package.json`)?
3. When publish the package, the `repository` field of `package.json` is required?
4. Can be different between the repository for publishing and the repository in `pacakge.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. `npm` gets them from the NPM package registry, and so does `yarn`, but Yarn probably has a proxy registry in front of it. In general, you can say, both tools fetch their packages from https://npmjs.com by default.
2. It gets the package as it was published (so, in short, the answer is "raw"). Building is up to the publisher and depends on the type of package. Often, some `prepublish` task builds something into `dist/` (or any other location in the package), and these files are also shipped with the package others then download. Building rarely happens after installing a package (exception here are library-wrapping packages built with node-gyp).
3. The repository field is not required, to my knowledge, but it is good practise to include it (it will be displayed on the NPM website, for example).
4. Technically, yes. You can just specify any repository in `repository`, but it wouldn't make much sense to specify one that isn't the source of the package.

If you in general want to read up more on how `npm` works, check out it's documentation over at https://docs.npmjs.com/